# Problems in linking LAPACK with Code:Blocks GNU fortran compiler Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, codeblocks, lapack

I want to link LAPACK library with my fortran code (.f90) on Ubuntu 14.04

I run this with terminal option 
`gfortran -o main main.f95 -L"usr/lib/lapack" -llapack` 
and it compiles with no error.
But in Code::Blocks, I create a fortran project and goto Project->Build options

[image]

And it gives error when I build the project
`gfortran error: usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so No such file or directory`

I do not understand what is going wrong. I also have LAPACK installed. 
These are files at `/usr/lib/lapack`
`liblapack.a  liblapack.so  liblapack.so.3  liblapack.so.3.0`

Any help?

Comment: Open the log file and show what exactly the IDE does behind the scenes.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the setting in the "Search Directories" tab is not happy with this IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where it says "Link libraries", where you currently have `/usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so`, you enter just `lapack` and `blas`.

Where it says "Other linker options:", and you have `-llapack` and `-lblas`, you leave it empty. If that fails, you might add `-L"usr/lib/lapack"` there, but you probably don't need to.

If you look at the "Build log" tab at the bottom, it should tell you amongst other things the `gfortran` command that it has executed.

Comment: This method solved the problem. I did not check the other method in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is strange; I would expect the command line one to cause problem:

```
gfortran -o main main.f95 -L"usr/lib/lapack" -llapack
```

You should have "/" at the beginning of the path name unless there is local tree in your porject defined as usr/lib/lapack. It can still work if some environments variables allow you to always have the location of libraries.

When it comes to your development environment (that I do not use) you do not need to add the full path to the library and the options -llapack together. You add -llapack when you provide only the path.

Comment: The `lapack` library is already in the `LIBRARY_PATH`, so adding a non-existing library path probably isn't much of a problem.

Comment: there is still something strange in the error from Code::Block, it says `gfortran error: usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so`, no "/" at the beginning at the path.